# Changing URL to something else?

Tags: javascript, html, url, browser

If I have a site "http://example.com/" is it possible to show in the URL (after loading the page) "bananas" instead of "http://example.com/"?

Comment: You want literally the word "bananas"?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible without redirecting to another page.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt possible with a redirect. You cant do it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can get is `window.location.hash = "bananas";` which produces `http://example.com/#bananas`.